# I can't send AJAX requests to my controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that containing a form, when I try to send my data using ajax I failed. This is my controller :

```
public function server()
{
    $name = $_REQUEST['nom'];
    $ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];
    $ftp = $_REQUEST['ftp'];
    $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
    $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO servers (id, name, ip, ftp, user, pass, active) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$ip', '$ftp', '$user', '$pass', '1');";
    echo $sql;
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

From console of my browser I have no error. Also when I try to show what's happened it's like telling me that's everything is ok.

And this is my view:

```
<!-- BEGIN FORM MODAL MARKUP -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="newserver" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newserverLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="newserverLabel">Ajoute nouveau serveur :</h4>
                    </div>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action="" id="newserverfrm" >
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="nom" class="control-label">Nom</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="ip" class="control-label">IP</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" class="form-control" placeholder="IP">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="ftp" class="control-label">FTP</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="ftp" id="ftp" class="form-control" placeholder="ex : ftpback-rbx{X}-{XX}.ovh.net">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="user" class="control-label">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="ex : nsXXXXXX.ip-YY-YY-YY.eu">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="pass" class="control-label">Mot de passe</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annule</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="newserver" value="Ajoute" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
        <!-- END FORM MODAL MARKUP -->
    </div><!--end #base-->
    <!-- END BASE -->

    <!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/libs/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/libs/autosize/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/libs/nanoscroller/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/source/App.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/source/AppNavigation.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/source/AppOffcanvas.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/source/AppCard.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/source/AppForm.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/source/AppNavSearch.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/source/AppVendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/demo/Demo.js"></script>
    <!-- END JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form.newserverfrm').on('submit', function(form){
                form.preventDefault();
                $.post('/add/server', $('form.newserverfrm').serialize(), function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: no answer. it's just seems every thing is ok

Comment: Do you mean you solved your own problem?

Comment: Instead of using "form.newserverfrm" in post use only id of form i.e. "#newserverfrm" i think this may be causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change :

```
$.post('/add/server', $('form.newserverfrm').serialize(), function(data){...
```

to

```
$.post('<?php site_url("add/server") ?>', $('form.newserverfrm').serialize(), function(data){...
```

Comment: i got this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: you can change `$config['base_url'] = ' ';` in `config` file to `$config['base_url'] = 'your url here ';`

Answer (score 0):

you  should take an action

i.e ,

Change

```
 $.post('/add/server', $('form.newserverfrm').serialize(), function(data){...
```

To

```
$.post('server', $('form.newserverfrm').serialize(), function(data){...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reeplace your code with these code

View page

!-- BEGIN FORM MODAL MARKUP -->
        
            
                
                    
                        ×
                        Ajoute nouveau serveur :
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    Nom
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    IP
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    FTP
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Nom d'utilisateur
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Mot de passe
                                
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                        
                            Annule

```
<!-- BEGIN JAVASCRIPT -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/spin.js/spin.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/autosize/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/nanoscroller/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/source/App.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/source/AppNavigation.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/source/AppOffcanvas.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/source/AppCard.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/source/AppForm.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/source/AppNavSearch.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/source/AppVendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/core/demo/Demo.js"></script>
<!-- END JAVASCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
```

function test()
        {

```
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'server.php',
        data : { },  
        async : false,
        success : function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }

        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please change the url : server  , avoid the .php ...... ok  . Also in data{ } used to pass your variables from , to get their values based on their ids

Comment: I tried using these code and send AJAX requestes to my controller